# Check if the site allows new user registration

Tags: users

In Drupal 7, on my frontpage custom template, i want to show a text if the site is allowing new users to register.
Any clues?
Thanks

Comment: You can do a variable_get call in template.php to check the value of the registration state, but I can’t recall he name of the variable. It’s located in the variables database table. Based on that value you can create a new template variable to show a message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a preprocess function for your template, add code something like:

```
$variables['is_registration_open'] = variable_get('user_register') == USER_REGISTER_VISITORS;
```

Then in your template:

```
<?php if ($is_registration_open) : ?>
<h3>Registration is open!</h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```